# Selecting value in Slider with Widget Test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I have a screen that contains a series of Sliders where the user can select if they agree/disagree with something, for example:

```
Slider(
  key: Key(questionId),
  min: 0,
  max: 5,
  divisions: 5,
  value: _value,
  onChanged: (value) {
     setState(() {
       _value = value;
     });
  },
),
```

I am currently implementing a UI test using `testWidgets`, in which the user selects multiple values in Sliders and then get stored when the user clicks on a button, and I'd like to be able to select a value, for example, to swipe the slider to value '2'.

How can I do that?

The only idea I have is to use `tapAt` with the exact pixel coordinates where the value is in the slider but seems extremely complicated to do.

For clarification I am asking about Widget Testing as described in: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/introduction

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's probably no longer needed, but since this was the only related question I found when looking for the answer myself, here is my solution:

WidgetTester has the functions 'drag/dragFrom/dragUntilVisible':

```
await tester.drag(find.byType(Slider), Offset(100, 0));
```

This will drag the Slider :)

Answer (score 4):

I built an extension which drags to a desired value. Hope this helps anyone ;)

```
extension SlideTo on WidgetTester {
  Future<void> slideToValue(Finder slider, double value,
      {double paddingOffset = 24.0}) async {
    final zeroPoint = this.getTopLeft(slider) +
        Offset(paddingOffset, this.getSize(slider).height / 2);
    final totalWidth = this.getSize(slider).width - (2 * paddingOffset);
    final calculatdOffset = value * (totalWidth / 100);
    await this.dragFrom(zeroPoint, Offset(calculatdOffset, 0));
  }
}
```